# connection issue / Oracle Express 11g in windows7 32bit

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, windows

I have an issue with Oracle Express 11g in windows7 32bit.
Everytime when I try to conncet to the database I get this error message.
How can I fix it please!

[image: Oracle Express 11g]

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to set the ORACLE_SID environment variable. This error usually means you are trying to connect to a database that doesn't exist. Also check that ORACLE_HOME is set correctly. If that doesn't fix it, check if the database service is started. If it is, check the alert log for error messages.

Comment: How Can I do this ? (exuse me Im a begginer)

Comment: Follow step 5 here to make sure the DB is started: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#CIHBCFDD

Comment: unfortunately, I get the error  message when I use SYSTEM and my password  to connect.

Comment: Did you start the database using Step 5.1 in the above document? Did you get any error messages when you did that, or during the installation?

Comment: Yes, the DB is started but when I put "connect System" & the password in the sqlplus cmd line I get this error message 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/rsehS.jpg

and even when I use this andress http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950 
I can't  connect

Comment: I set oracle_home and oracle_sid in windows 7 but I have the same problem :(

Comment: Try connecting as sysdba instead.
> connect / as sysdba

Comment: when I use : connect / as sysdba 

it say

connected to an idle instance

Comment: Then the database is not started. Type "startup".